# Global shortcut to play/pause YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I would like to play and pause my youtube video with a global shorcut, for example alt
+A, in anywhere either in chrome or in another app. Could  you help me please?, I'm using Windows 11

Comment: Normally the [Play/Pause toggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_control_symbols#Symbols) from a keyboard should work. If you don't have such a key on your keyboard, you could try making a program taking a shortcut such as `Alt + A` sending the `Play/Pause toggle` key code. For other readers, could you precise the operating system you are using?

Comment: Wow, you're right, I changed my ctrl(right) button to the Play/Pause toggle with powertoys but only works for my default windows player , what else can i do?

Comment: Note that you haven't answered my question "could you precise the operating system you are using?"

Comment: Yeah, I added in the description of the answer that, I'm using windows 11, sorry for that 

Answer (score 0):

look at chrome extension HotKey Music Controller: YouTube, Spotify. You can use AutoHotKey to map Alt+A to keyboard play/pause. Script will be something like:

```
!a::send {Media_Play_Pause}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this great "**Streamkeys**" Chrome extension for that for years: https://github.com/berrberr/streamkeys

---

It is also available on the Chrome Store, but be careful with that version because it has just recently changed the owner:
see [this original author's comment](https://github.com/berrberr/streamkeys/issues/1098#issuecomment-1821616102) (and the one a few comments below about how to install the extension manually from the code).